# Lazy Loading Modules in Angular 2 (v5) Application

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, module, lazy-loading

I'm having trouble making lazy loading work on an Angular 2 (version 5.1.3) project.

I’m following Todd Motto's article on this [Lazy Loading Code Splitting](https://toddmotto.com/lazy-loading-angular-code-splitting-webpack), and can’t quite make the last mile to get it working.

I have an app with multiple modules, several of which I want to lazy load (most users don’t use the functionality, and the app itself is large with everything bundled in).

The app.module route config looks like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'login', 
    pathMatch: 'full'
   },
  { path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  { path: 'home', 
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  { path: 'reports-engine', 
    loadChildren: './reportsengine/reportsengine.module#ReportsEngineModule'
  },
  { path: '**', 
    component: NotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

And the ReportsEngine module:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: ReportsComponent,
    children: [{ 
      path: '', 
          redirectTo: 'reports-engine',
          pathMatch: 'full'
        },
      { 
      path: 'account', 
          component: Account
        },
      { 
      path: 'accounts-manage', 
          component: AccountsManage
        },
      {
      path: '**', 
          component: NotFoundComponent
      }]
  }
];
```

My webpack.config (the relevant parts) are here:

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    path: path.resolve(cwd, 'build'),
    publicPath: './build/',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
},

rules.push({
    test: /\.ts$/, 
        loaders: [
            'awesome-typescript-loader',
            'angular2-template-loader'
        ] ,
    test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
        loaders: [
            'angular-router-loader'
        ] ,
    include: [
        path.resolve(cwd, 'app')
    ]
});
```

Currently it's only building the main app.js and vendor.js files (and .map files), not the 0.chunk.js etc. files.

And when I navigate to the /reports-engine url, I get a 'page not found', which I'm expecting the ReportsComponent.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: add logging router events to the console, not sure it's webpack's problem

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Can you provide a little more detail on where to log the events, and specifically what I'm looking for? Thanks! (I was reading through all your Medium posts this afternoon hoping you'd covered LazyLoading in one of them - some incredibly useful material there).

Comment: cool. just add `RouterModule.forRoot(..., { enableTracing: true })` and add to the answer what it logs when you navigate to `reports-engine`

Answer (score 0):

ReportEngine Module.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: ReportsComponent,
    children: [    
      { 
        path: 'account', 
        component: Account
      },
      { 
        path: 'accounts-manage', 
        component: AccountsManage
      },
      {
        path: '**', 
        component: NotFoundComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Change Like this it will work.

if you want children path:'' ->check put like this

```
 children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: AboutComponent
      }
 ]
```

if you have any doubt please visit this link it is simply to do the lazy loading

https://scotch.io/courses/routing-angular-2-applications/lazy-loading

I hope it will help.